How to create a custom annotation that do the task of @Schedule annotation in java conditionally
Previously I used @Schedule annotation to execute some methods according to some schedule for example,
@Schedule(minute ="*/5", hour = "*", persistent = false, info = "Every 5 minute")
public void newMethod() {
     // Some tasks invoked every five minutes
}

Now I need to invoke this method in every five minutes only if some global variable called isLeader is true.
The obvious answer is to add if statement into the newMethod() but since there are many usages of @Scheduler annotation and there are many changes to do if we are to choose that way.
Is there any convenient way to do it?
My thought is to build a custom annotation called @MyScheduler that accepts extra attribute called isLeader other than @Scheduler attributes. I tried to do it and failed.
Is anybody have some experiences on this kind of custom annotation building that doing some tasks conditionally, please help to solve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

The annotation is just a marker. What you need first is some facility that processes that annotation.
This means that your @MyScheduler may have been implemented correctly, according to your specification, but there is nothing that takes care of it.
Annotations can be processed during compile time (by an implementation of javax.annotation.processing.Processor) or through Reflection during runtime. But for your custom annotations you have to provide that facility yourself.
